# Why does std::function not work with function templates?

Tags: c++, templates

I am starting to work with templates and I am trying to figure out why the following does not work.

```
class testclass1
{
public:
    
    template <typename...Ts>
    using TFunc = std::function<void(Ts*...)>;
    
    template <typename...Ts>
    void SetFunction(TFunc<Ts...> tf)
    {
        // Do something
    }
};

template<typename...Ts>
class testclass2
{
public:
    
    using TFunc = std::function<void(Ts*...)>;
    
    void SetFunction(TFunc tf)
    {
        // Do something
    }
};

void some_function(std::string*, double*)
{
    
}

int main()
{
    
    testclass1 tc1;
    testclass2<std::string, double> tc2;
    
    testclass1::TFunc<std::string, double> tf1 = some_function;

    tc1.SetFunction<std::string, double>(tf1);
    tc1.SetFunction<std::string, double>(testclass1::TFunc<std::string, double>{tf1});
    
    tc2.SetFunction(some_function);
    
    tc1.SetFunction<std::string, double>(some_function);
}
```

All works fine except the last version
`tc1.SetFunction<std::string, double>(some_function);`
which is actually what I would like to do since it has much less boilerplate and since I don't want testclass1 to require template arguments.

The last line gives the following compilation error:

*No matching member function for call to 'SetFunction'*

1. Candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<void (std::__1::basic_string *, double *, type-parameter-0-0 *...)>' against 'void (*)(std::__1::basic_string *, double *)'

I don't understand what is the additional "type-parameter-0-0". Intuitively, this looks much like problems linked to an implicit *this pointer, but I don't see why TFunc would be a member function and have an implicit *this pointer (or is this linked to std::function?). Also, moving the code `template <typename...Ts> using TFunc = std::function<void(Ts*...)>;` outside of testclass1 does not change anything.

From browsing different related Q&As, it seems that you cannot use std::function with template functions. Is this the problem here?

Is there a way to make `tc1.SetFunction<std::string, double>(some_function);`work within testclass1?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I'm trying to wrap my head around the explanation, I think I sort of get it but then---thinking about it---I'm still not 100% sure. Consider the following code:

```
template <typename...Ts>
using test_tuple = std::tuple<Ts...>;

template <typename...Ts>
void test_func(test_tuple<Ts...> tup)
{
    // Do something
    // e.g., PrintTuple(tup);
}

int main()
{
    test_tuple<std::string, double> tt{"Hi", 3.1459f};
    test_func<std::string>(tt);
}
```

In that case, only `std::string` is specified in the parameter  pack and the double is deduced (so not all parameters are specified in the pack). But why does it work in this case and I don't get an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *it seems that you cannot use `std::function` with template functions*

No, the issue has nothing to do with `std::function`.

The problem is the failed deduction of the [template parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack). Normally, when you specify all template arguments explicitly, no deduction is performed.

```
    tc1.SetFunction<std::string, double>(some_function); // no deduction needed, right?
```

But in case of a *pack*, a deduction is *always* performed. It's because it's possible to specify *some* pack arguments and let the compiler deduce the rest, and there's no way to know if you specified only some or all the arguments.

But `std::function<void(std::string*, double*)>` can't be deduced from `void(*)(std::string*, double*)` (and user-defined conversions are not considered during deduction). Hence the error:

> `template argument deduction/substitution failed:`
> `mismatched types 'std::function<void(Ts* ...)>' and 'void (*)(std::string*, double*)'`

<sup>(note - there is no mention of "*type-parameter-0-0*" in [GCC 11 output](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fzXhk79SApinwih8), so your compiler might be outdated).</sup>

Now, to fix this, we can introduce a non-deduced context to the parameter of `SetFunction`. Then the substitution will be performed from the provided type arguments.

For example using an identity template:

```
template<typename T>
struct type_identity {
    using type = T;
};

class testclass1
{
public:
    
    template <typename...Ts>
    using TFunc = std::function<void(Ts*...)>;

    template <typename...Ts>
    void SetFunction(typename type_identity<TFunc<Ts...>>::type tf)
    {
        // Do something
    }
};
```

([Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hcuHC8mmXi3KaIl8))

---

With regard to the update and the follow-up question - `test_tuple` parameters are happily deduced from a `test_tuple` argument - there's no conversion involved, it's just pattern matching. But `std::function` is a class, it can be constructed from a *function pointer*, but these are different types, so one cannot be deduced from the other.